# Javascript ES6: Get specific array from inside of JSON array and iterate them using map

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON at https://api.myjson.com/bins/9jyq4

```
"response": [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Star Wars",
    "project": [
      "Star Wars Proj1",
      "Star Wars Proj2",
      "Star Wars Proj3",
      "Star Wars Proj4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Back to the Future",
    "project": [
      "Back to the Future Proj1",
      "Back to the Future Proj2",
      "Back to the Future Proj3",
      "Back to the Future Proj4"
    ]
  },
  ..
  ..
```

I have two pickers. "Title" and "Projects"
I am populating title picker using.

```
<Picker
  mode="dialog"
  selectedValue={this.state.Movietitle}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => 
  this.setState({ Movietitle: itemValue });
  }
  enabled={!this.state.inRide}
  >
  { 
    this.state.responseData.map((item) => (
    <Picker.Item label={item.title} value={item.id} key={item.id} />))
  }
</Picker>
```

So now I want to populate second picker "Projects" using choice selected from first picker. Just need help in making a map query. Thanks

Comment: array of specific ids, which are they?

Comment: how exactly do you want it.Give a sample.

Comment: updated the question. Please have look

Answer (score 0):

Use filter method to get tan array of object where the id matches, then use map method on it

```js
let response = [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Star Wars",
    "project": [
      "Star Wars Proj1",
      "Star Wars Proj2",
      "Star Wars Proj3",
      "Star Wars Proj4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Back to the Future",
    "project": [
      "Back to the Future Proj1",
      "Back to the Future Proj2",
      "Back to the Future Proj3",
      "Back to the Future Proj4"
    ]
  }
]

function getObject(srchId) {
  let __obj = response.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id === srchId;


  })
  return __obj;
}

getObject('2').map(function(item) {

  //rest of the code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access each project title by `find`ing currently selected response item and simply mapping through each item in the `project` property of that response item.

Like this:

```
render() {
    const { responseData, Movietitle, selectedProject } = this.state;
    const selectedMovie = responseData.find(item => item.id === Movietitle);

    return (
        <Picker
            mode="dialog"
            selectedValue={selectedProject}
            onValueChange={project => this.setState({ selectedProject: project })}
        >
            { 
                selectedMovie.project.map((project, projectIndex) => (
                    <Picker.Item label={project} value={project} key={`${Movietitle}-${projectIndex}`} />
                ))
            }
        </Picker>
    );
}
```